# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpcre.1.dylib

Tags: django, uwsgi

I've plugged in wsgi to my Django application.
I'm using macOS High Sierra - 10.13.3.
Application runs fine with the below command.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But when I use wsgi to start the server. It fails.

```
$> uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mymac/anaconda3/bin/uwsgi
  Reason: image not found
[1]    27677 abort      uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :8000
chdir = /app
module = app.wsgi:application
master = 1
processes = 2
threads = 2
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with the uwsgi configuration?

Answer (score 7):

I met the same question with you when trying on macOS. I guess you install `uwsgi` using `pip install uwsgi`. I suggest you trying another method using `brew install uwsgi`.

First you should remove uwsgi from directory `usr/local/bin`.

Second you should execute `brew install uwsgi`.

Comment: in my case i also had to do '$ brew link uwsgi'